# Обрезать вывод команды в bash

Tags: linux, bash

Пишу скрипт для сканирования подсети. Должно вывести мне IP и имя машины

```
#!bin/bash
nokey()
{
echo "Ключ --all выводит IP-адреса и символьные имена всех узлов в текущей подсети"
echo "Ключ --target=X.X.X.X выводит список открытых системных портов TCP"
}
all()
{
 nbtscan 10.5.115.0/24 
}
if [ -z "$1" ] 
then 
nokey
else 
case "$1" in
--all) all ;;
--target) #targetfunc ;;
esac
fi
```

Выводит такую тему
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1) Как мне обрезать вывод чтобы выводились только первые 2 столбца(grep или sed)?
2) Как сделать ключ --target?

Comment: 1. Лучше все таки `awk` для работы с столбцами. 2. применить что то вроде `nmap`

Comment: используйте опцию `-e` программы *nbtscan* - вывод "в формате /etc/hosts", т.е., только имя и ip-адрес.

Answer (score 1):

Используй awk для нарезки по столбцам, по типу:

```
nbtscan 192.168.0.0/24 | awk {'print $1,$2'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

nokey()
{
    echo "Ключ --all выводит IP-адреса и символьные имена всех узлов в текущей подсети"
    echo "Ключ --target=X.X.X.X выводит список открытых системных портов TCP"
}

all()
{
    local net="$1"

    nbtscan -k  "${net}/24"
}

target()
{
    local ip="$1"

    nbtscan"$ip"
}

main()
{
    if [  "$#" = 0 ]; then 
        nokey
    else 
        case "$1" in
            --all)
                all "$2"
            ;;
            --target) 
                target "$2"
            ;;
        esac
    fi
}

main "$@"
# End of script_name
```

Не пойму, зачем так заморачиватся над травиальной задачей. Для себя открыл ключ *-oG* в **nmap** сразу готовит вывод для грепания (grep, awk)

```
~$ nmap -oG - 172.16.31.76/24
# Nmap 7.40 scan initiated Wed Jul 12 22:25:36 2017 as: nmap -oG - 172.16.31.76/24
Host: 172.16.31.1 ()    Status: Up
Host: 172.16.31.1 ()    Status: Up
Host: 172.16.31.21 ()   Status: Up
Host: 172.16.31.21 ()   Status: Up
Host: 172.16.31.76 ()   Status: Up
Host: 172.16.31.76 ()   Status: Up
Host: 172.16.31.106 ()  Status: Up
Host: 172.16.31.106 ()  Status: Up
# Nmap done at Wed Jul 12 22:25:41 2017 -- 256 IP addresses (4 hosts up) scanned in 4.97 seconds
```